# Ruby on Rails Routing for Wildcard URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I was trying to pull a segment from the URL and since I'm a rookie, kind of confused by the routing.

My code to get the last segment works fine, it's my routing that is messed up.

Ideally the URL would like this:

```
http://localhost.com/track/item/1234
```

I'm using Rails v4.0.8 & Ruby v2.0.0p451

The error is *No route matches [GET] "/track/item/1234"*

Here's the whole routes.rb file:

```
SepContact::Application.routes.draw do

  get "track/item"
  get "track/item/:id"  
  get "contacts/contact"
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]

end
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you put the whole routes.rb file please?

Comment: Shouldn't your routes be "track" instead of "tracking"?

Comment: I updated the url, still kicking same error

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: The    rake routes  command gives this error: _ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes._

Comment: What is the name on the controller that's supposed to receive this request?

Comment: The class is _TrackController_ and then i _def item_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CWitty's should work as well but here is a more explicit format.

```
  match "track/items",      to: 'controller#index', via: :get, as: "items"
  match "track/items/:id",  to: 'controller#show', via: :get, as: "item"
```

Note I updated your url to be more rails like items rather than item

I think most of your problem is with the track segment of the url.
I don't see how get 'track/items' would map the the items#index  controller / method
I think the match method would be needed here to explicitly map the url to the correct controller and method.

Is there a good reason you are naming you url like that?

You can read all about routing here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Here is the section of the above document that discusses using the match method:

3.7 HTTP Verb Constraints
In general, you should use the get, post, put, patch and delete methods to constrain a route to a particular verb. You can use the match method with the :via option to match multiple verbs at once:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

You can match all verbs to a particular route using via: :all:

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all
```

Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security implications. In general, you should avoid routing all verbs to an action unless you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes should be like:

```
SepContact::Application.routes.draw do

  get "track/item/:id", to: 'controller#action'
  get "track/item", to: 'controller#action' 
  get "contacts/contact" to: 'controller#action' 
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]

end
```

You need to specify a `to:` pointing to a controller and action unless you use the `resource` or `resources` helper.